# I am getting this Error while installing any package in R

Tags: r

When trying to install a package I'm getting the following:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/survival_2.41-3.zip' Content type 'application/zip' length 5242797 bytes (5.0 MB)
```

Can one explain it?

Comment: This is not an error. It is trying to download the package through that link from **cran** repository. Maybe your internet speed is slow; hence it gets stuck there.

Comment: Did you mean to paste something else, maybe more of the lines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Just write from the console:

```
install.packages("survival")
```

to call the library

```
library(survival)
```

That's it. You don't have to download the .zip file if you can do it directly from the console.